# How to round to 2 decimals in python?

Tags: python

```
print("Worth: " + GREEN2 + str(GemValue) + END)
```

How do I round GemValue to 2 decimals?

Sometimes I get values like 50.9999999999992

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you

```
str(round(GemValue,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("{:.2f}".format(GemValue))
```

should do the trick